# Some CPU Information

Tags: c++, windows

Well, i we're working on a CPU Controller, which shows all CPU Data. I've managed to get Windows Version, Windows Service Pack, Processor Name, Processor Speed, Processor Identifier(Though Registry Vals).
But now i don't have any idea of how to get the processor Instructions, Caches, Video Card Information (Video Card Name, Available Memory, Total Memory), Southbridge Information (Ethernet Information)

Well, i've been loking on WinAPI but i get it very hard to work. I've looked over google 3 hours but nothing. :/ Any idea? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at:

```
MEMORYSTATUSEX status;
GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&status);
```

For RAM and Virtual RAM

For video memory
vista:

```
CreateDXGIFactory API via GetProcAddress()
```

Below vista, d3d9 API

```
GetAvailableTextureMemory()
```

Comment: Yes, i've been looking on that. (Video). I also looked on MSDN. But i don't get an idea.

Comment: Well. I've done this:

{
 LPDIRECT3D9 d3d = NULL;
 PDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3ddDevice = NULL;
 d3d = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);
 D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
 ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));
 HRESULT DeviceErr = d3d->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, NULL, D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &d3dpp, &d3ddDevice);
 return d3dpp->GetAvailableTextureMem();
}

But this doesn't return anything. (Now i'm using a DLL to get Memory).

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) ? [This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/44e5162d-044b-4a8a-a0a8-1056b55d0a81) appears to suggest you can get SouthBridge info through WMI.

Comment: Yes. I've done this. I don't know how to continue. :/

{
 IDXGIFactory * factory;
 CreateDXGIFactory(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory), (void**)&factory);
 UINT a = 0;
 IDXGIAdapter *adapter;
 while(factory->EnumAdapters(a, &adapter) != DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND) {
  ++a;
 }
}

Answer (score 3):

Gonna expand cppanda's answer a bit:

Concerning video cards, there's sometimes more than one in the system. The best way to get oodles n oodles of information on them is to use DirectX.

If it's meant to be compatible with Vista and up, you can use DXGI, which is cleaner and easier to use in my opinion.

First things first, you'll need to create a DXGI factory...

```
IDXGIFactory* DXGIFactoryPtr = 0;
HRESULT RetVal = CreateDXGIFactory(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory), (void**)&DXGIFactoryPtr);
if (FAILED(RetVal)) {/*Error Checking*/;}
```

then use it to loop through each adapter...

```
unsigned short I = 0;
IDXGIAdapter* AdapterPtr = 0;
std::vector<IDXGIAdapter*> Adapters;
while (DXGIFactoryPtr->EnumAdapters(I, &AdapterPtr) != DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND)
{
    Adapters.push_back(AdapterPtr);
    ++I;
}
```

From here, you can see if Direct3D 10 is supported:

```
if (Adapters[I]->CheckInterfaceSupport(__uuidof(ID3D10Device), 0) == S_OK)
{   /*D3D10 is supported for this device*/; }
```

Enumerate attached outputs [I.E. Moniters], which could be useful for checking which resolutions are supported and such:

```
unsigned short J = 0;
IDXGIOutput* OutputPtr = 0;
std::vector<IDXGIOutput*> Outputs;
while (Adapter[I]->EnumOutputs(J, &OutputPtr) != DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND)
{
    Outputs.push_back(OutputPtr);
    ++J;
}
```

and get a description:

```
DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC AdapterDescription;
Adapter[I]->GetDesc(&AdapterDescription);
```

AdapterDescription has the fields `Description`, `VenderId`, `DeviceId`, `SubSysId`, `Revision`, `DedicatedVideoMemory`, `DedicatedSystemMemory`, `SharedSystemMemory`, and `AdapterLuid`.
`AdapterLuid` is a system specific unique identifier for the card, but all the others should be very obvious given the names.

Beyond that, it becomes vendor specific I think.

For DirectX 9, which is available for Windows 2000 up, it's a bit different. First, you have to create the core Direct3D9 object:

```
IDirect3D9* D3D9 = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);
if (D3D9 == 0)
{   /* Error checking*/;    }
```

Then get the adapter count:

```
unsigned short AdapterCount = (unsigned short)D3D9->GetAdapterCount();
```

Then loop through them, getting their identifiers:

```
D3DADAPTER_IDENTIFIER9* Identifiers = new D3DADAPTER_IDENTIFIER9[AdapterCount];
HRESULT RetVal = 0;
for (unsigned short I = 0; I < AdapterCount; ++I)
{
    RetVal = D3D9->GetAdapterIdentifier(I, 0, &Identifiers[I]);
    if (FAILED(RetVal))
    {   /* Error checking*/;    }
}
```

Again, most of the fields should be self explanitory. WHQLLevel is information on if and when Microsoft tested that driver's compatability with Windows, and for the most part can be safely ignored. Using close to the same method above, you can also acquire a device's capabilities using GetDeviceCaps, which would give you more information.

As cppanda said, you can use IDirect3DDevice9::GetAvailableTextureMem(), but that requires you to create the device before querying it. Anything the above two don't indicate require creating the device before retrieving it.

Hope that helps~

[Side note, a lot of this was pulled out of the DirectX SDK so code's theirs, not mine.]

Comment: Woah. Works. Thank you. I basically never tryed using DirectX or OpenGL. Since i still don't have any good game project. :P

Comment: Glad it helped. If you have any questions or anything, feel free to ask, I'll keep an eye on this topic for a few days to make sure you're set :3

Comment: What does GetDesc does? When i tryed it i got 0012E1F0. o.O
Since i did &AdapterDescription.Description and it returned that. o.O

Comment: GetDesc is Get Description, it fills out a DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC field with various bits of info. If 0012E1F0 is what GetDesc returned, it's a return code that basically means success, with a few other bits of information. If you mean AdapterDescription->Description is equal to that, it's a pointer to a wide string (Unicode) containing the adapter description. You can convert it to an ASCII string [with possible data loss] by using a loop to copy each character from the wide string into a new char string. See here: http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-336106.html

Answer (score 2):

Well, the [CPUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID) instruction gives a bit of info. Not all that you need, but it's a start.